# How to maven multiple directories in java?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Im having 2 seperate packages under src folder. i wonder how to maven this project?

```
src
```

-- com.firstpackage
  -- com.secondPackage

Comment: I hope you have them under src/main/java or if these things are tests under src/test/java ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are in one src folder this should not be a problem.
Your typical maven project will look like this:

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

So even if you have many packages/folders within src/ that should be no problem.

There is a good guide [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) how to set up a maven project in 5 mintues.

Comment: what if under src/main/java you have two different packages, such as com/mycompany/app/app.java and com/mycompany2/app/AnotherApp.java. how to configure this on pom.xml?

Comment: All packages under src/main/java/ will be "detected" and compiled